# Tensorflow on AMD GPU

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, gpu, amd-rocm

I have AMD RX 470 and want to run Deep Neural Net using my GPU. I have checked ROCm and could not understand how to get this running. I also could not find any simple instructions to install.
I am new to Ubuntu, if anyone can provide simple instructions that will be very helpful.
Thank You

Comment: @swiftg i installed using these instructions but the speed is too slow. There's also written memoryClockRate (GHz) 1.25. I don't have much knowledge about the hardware but my CPU ( i5 7th gen) has better clockrate.

Comment: You can do internet search for why GPUs are used for deep learning. Your original question has been answered.

Comment: @swiftg it seems that the link you provided is dead, do you have an updated one?

Comment: [Updated ROCm docs](https://github.com/ROCmSoftwarePlatform/tensorflow-upstream/blob/develop-upstream/README.ROCm.md) . Google is your friend if this doesn't help.